# Using the iRODS Python Client to "put" directories to iRODS

Tags: python

I'm working on a python app which makes use of the [iRODS Python Client](https://github.com/irods/python-irodsclient/) for storing data with iRODS. By using the icommand `iput` together with the `-r` option (recursive) in my terminal like

```
$ iput -r <some_directory>
```

I'm able to *put* whole directories to iRODS (where they will be passed to my configured resources and saved as data object). Since I wan't to use the iRODS Python client I'm looking for a similar option of *putting* directories to iRODS. So far I use:

```
from irods.session import iRODSSession
irods_sess = iRODSSession(...)

irods_sess.data_objects.put("some_file", "path_to_resource")
```

which works for files but not for directories.
From the [source code](https://github.com/irods/python-irodsclient/blob/6a0bc574504c33de0b53fdb0e0b11b889b996818/irods/manager/data_object_manager.py#L60) of the Python iRODS client I read that the `put` function accepts keyworded arguments:

```
def put(self, file, irods_path, **options):
    ...
```

but I cannot figure out how to pass a recursive-like option as a keyworded argument.

**Does anybody know how to `put` directories to iRODS using the iRODS Python client?**

Comment: see the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/irods/python-irodsclient/issues/122) at the iRODS python client github